# Given compression ratio for a naturally aspirated engine, how do I calculate the expected compression pressure?

Tags: engine-theory, compression-testing

I've started learning more about cars, and I have a question. How do I know what compression pressure I should expect during a compression test?

With a naturally aspirated engine, I think I can use Boyle's Law. Assuming an naturally aspirated engine, I would expect the calculation to work like this.

P<sub>tdc</sub>*V<sub>tdc</sub>=P<sub>bdc</sub>*V<sub>bdc</sub>

Where P is pressure and V is volume. Tdc and bdc are top dead center and bottom dead center respectively.

Rearranging by dividing both sides by V<sub>tdc</sub>:

P<sub>tdc</sub>=P<sub>bdc</sub>*V<sub>bdc</sub>/V<sub>tdc</sub>

I think the compression ratio is equivalent to V<sub>bdc</sub>/V<sub>tdc</sub>, so I can rewrite the expression as:

P<sub>tdc</sub>=P<sub>bdc</sub>*c

Where c is compression ratio.

It seems like P<sub>bdc</sub>should be the same as atmospheric pressure in a naturally aspirated engine.

Okay, so let's make it concrete and assume that compression ratio is 8.8:1 and the atmospheric pressure is 1007mBar.

P<sub>tdc</sub>=1007mBar * 8.8
P<sub>tdc</sub>=8861mBar or 129psi

Assuming that a good compression test should measure at least 75% of that, I would expect 129psi*.75=97psi is the minimum to consider a cylinder in this engine to pass a compression test.

Is my thinking correct?

Comment: Where does volumetric efficiency fit into your equation? You are assuming you get 100% fill of the cylinder, where normal volumetric efficiency for ICEs can range anywhere from ~60% for less efficient engines up to over 105+% for very efficient ones (like NASCAR engines). You have to know approximately where your VE is at and include it in your calcs. Also, just thinking about it, I'm not seeing anything for temperature, either. Higher temps means less dense air, which will affect the pressure as well.

Comment: Another thing to consider is leakage past the rings. While this is a small amount, it would still need to factor in.

Comment: On temperature, is that significant during a compression test on a cold engine? I haven't found anything in the car's shop manual about expected compression or VE. Measuring that world probably require lab instrumentation, I would guess?